# for loop that adds index inside arraylist

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, indexing

I have an arraylist called filterBookings()which is getting values from comboboxes and parsing them since they are Gregorian calendar.  if the Gregorian calendar is matching the user inputs (using equals.()) the index of the matching date should be added to another arraylist called filteredBookings. 
Should i use the for loop? or another way? And i am calling the method to a button.

```
 ArrayList <GregorianCalendar> filteredBookings = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList <GregorianCalendar> dates = new ArrayList<>();   

 public void filterBookings() throws ParseException {
    String day = String.valueOf(cmbDay.getSelectedItem());
    String month = String.valueOf(cmbMonth.getSelectedItem());
    String year = String.valueOf(cmbYear.getSelectedItem());

    String sdates = (day + "/"+ month + "/"+ year);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MMMM/yyyy");
    Date date2 = null;

    date2 = df.parse(sdates);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(date2);
    filteredBookings.add((GregorianCalendar) calendar);

    if (dates.equals(filteredBookings)) {
        for(int i = 0; i < filteredBookings.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i+": "+filteredBookings.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The expected results are when the user presses the button and the dates chosen from the user match the filteredBookings, an index of the matched date should be added to the filteredBookings list.

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @NicholasK                                                                                                         
            if (dates.equals(filteredBookings)){

            for(int i = 0; i < filteredBookings.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(i+": "+filteredBookings.get(i));
            }

               }

Comment: What are the values in the list? How do you expect help without providing *all* required information.

Comment: The values of the list are stored in a txt file @NicholasK

Comment: **You should not use the `Calendar` classes anymore.** They are obsolete. Use the new Java Date and Time API (from the `java.time` package) instead.

Comment: This is a school project an unfortunately we have to use that so...